# Plugins not activated after update?

Tags: plugins, admin

I recently noticed that after manually updating any plugin it is left deactivated.

Is this the correct operation? Or might there be a problem with my install?

Thanks

Comment: I've noticed the same, but it's never been a problem. After the plugin update is complete, and the *Plugins* page re-loads (showing the updated plugin as inactive), try refreshing the page; does it show the plugin active again?

Comment: Thanks - no, the plugin is deactivated and has to be activated again. I'm sure it didn't used to be this way. It might be an issue simply because I manage a few sites and would often bulk update plugins, but didn't realise I then had to go back and reactivate them all :O

Answer (score 0):

After manual update, plugins are deactivated by default.  It's like installing a new plugin all over again.